# How to query a JTS QuadTree using a query envelope with holes

Tags: java, jts-topology-suite, quadtree

I have a Java Topology Suite QuadTree containing Points, now I'm trying to query the QuadTree with a polygon that contains a hole.  Here's how I create the polygon.

```
//Method will create a searchable Polygon in the shape of a donut.
public Polygon searchAreaPoly(double outterBoundry, double innerBoundry) {

    Coordinate center = MyIndex.getWGSCoord(longitude, latitude);
    GeometricShapeFactory gsf = new GeometricShapeFactory();

    gsf.setCentre(center);
    gsf.setNumPoints(20);
    LinearRing[] holes = null;
    GeometryFactory fact = new GeometryFactory();

    //create the hole in the shape if innerBoundry is > 0
    if (innerBoundry > 0) {
        gsf.setSize(innerBoundry);
        Polygon innerPoly = gsf.createCircle();
        Coordinate[] innerCoords = innerPoly.getCoordinates();
        LinearRing hole = fact.createLinearRing(innerCoords);
        holes = new LinearRing[]{hole};
    }

    //create the outter boundry
    gsf.setSize(outterBoundry);
    Polygon outterPoly = gsf.createCircle();
    Coordinate[] outterCoords = outterPoly.getCoordinates();
    LinearRing shell = fact.createLinearRing(outterCoords);

    Polygon searchPoly = fact.createPolygon(shell, holes);

    return searchPoly;
}
```

Here's how I am querying the QuadTree;

```
//create polygon to search for points the intersect with it
Polygon polygon = data_bounds.searchAreaPoly(shell, hole);

List<MyQuadNode> items = quadTree.query(polygon.getEnvelopeInternal());
```

However the QuadTree returns a list that doesn't remove the Points the fall within the hole, no matter how big the hole.  Does anyone know how to do this, or even if it is possible?

Comment: I believe that quadtree holds the envelope of the geometry and envelope can't have holes. Best you could do is to make an envelope for the hole as well. Features which are stictly inside the hole could be removed from what you find from the index for the whole polygon. Speed-up is probably worth the trouble only if the hole is very big.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do doesn't really make sense. Quadtree.query works by intersecting the extents of the elements with a rectangular extent. It's up to you to further filter them.

However, you can use the [overloaded version of query](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/index/quadtree/Quadtree.html#query(com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Envelope,%20com.vividsolutions.jts.index.ItemVisitor)) with a subclass of [ItemVisitor](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/index/ItemVisitor.html) to achieve what you want.

```
public class QtreeTest {

    public static class HoleVisitor implements ItemVisitor {

        private List<Object> result;
        private Polygon filter;

        public HoleVisitor(Polygon filter, List<Object> result) {
            this.result = result;
            this.filter = filter;
        }

        @Override
        public void visitItem(Object obj) {
            if(filter.contains((Geometry) obj))
                result.add(obj);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        Quadtree t = new Quadtree();
        Polygon p = (Polygon) new WKTReader().read("POLYGON((0 0, 10 0, 10 10, 0 10, 0 0), (2 2, 2 8, 8 8, 8 2, 2 2))");

        Point pt;
        GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();
        for(int i=0;i<10;++i) {
            pt = gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(Math.random() * 10.0, Math.random() * 10.0));
            t.insert(pt.getEnvelopeInternal(), pt);
        }

        System.out.println("Filter on envelope");
        List<Object> result = t.query(p.getEnvelopeInternal());
        for(Object r:result)
            System.out.println(r);

        System.out.println("Filter with a hole");
        result = new ArrayList<Object>();
        t.query(p.getEnvelopeInternal(), new HoleVisitor(p, result));
        for(Object r:result)
            System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

With this code, my output is:

```
Filter on envelope
POINT (8.080553167044306 0.769379948630533)
POINT (4.569154948368714 4.153733384631248)
POINT (5.92938526520641 3.1663861099889603)
POINT (2.3904730266232455 7.900178460639396)
POINT (5.3909389056227885 5.740854801361649)
POINT (5.493532978665588 4.639022578600436)
POINT (4.736884600312752 5.631310976535514)
POINT (7.076479161641357 5.435151697017327)
POINT (9.409961828398178 2.126750667639794)
POINT (8.753077632261641 6.4171226291983245)

Filter with a hole
POINT (8.080553167044306 0.769379948630533)
POINT (9.409961828398178 2.126750667639794)
POINT (8.753077632261641 6.4171226291983245)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer this makes sense, do you know what the big O is for the query method?

Comment: The efficiency of the [Quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) search is O(log n), and the visitor only selects points that have passed the envelope test. But the visitor implementation looks like it's O(n) (because it iterates over the list of results). In most cases it'll be very fast. You'd have to have a pretty ridiculous query -- a big envelope with a giant hole -- to get a result in linear time. But that would indicate a problem with your design, not the algorithm.

Comment: In case I wasn't clear, the visitor iterates over the list of results _that have passed_ the envelope test, not on the entire list of items.

Comment: (Also, the `contains` code has to run on each iteration of the loop, which is an important thing to consider.)